# Emit an event when a variable changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, module

I want to **emit an event** whenever **variable changes** but it doesn't work.

**Here is the module:**

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events");

const watcher = new EventEmitter();

let variable = 0;
let previous = 0;

function reassign(value) {
  variable = value;
}
module.exports = watcher;
module.exports.reassign = reassign;
while (true) {
    if (variable !== previous) {
        watcher.emit("change", previous, variable);
        previous = variable;
    } else
        console.log(variable); // output: 0
}
```

**Here is the main file:**

```js
const watcher = require("./watcher.js");
watcher.on("change", (prev, variable) => {
  console.log(prev, variable);
});
watcher.reassign(10);
```

The issue is that the **reassign()** function doesn't modify the variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: The suggestion is to not block the app with endless loop. You can check that main file never gets past require call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to change the `module.exports`. Instead of declaring the entire exports as the watcher class, put both inside an object and declare them seperately.

Example:

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const watcher = new EventEmitter();

let variable = 0;

/**
  * Reassign the variable
  * @param value The new value
  */
function reassign(value) {
    watcher.emit("change", variable, value);
    variable = value;
}

module.exports = { watcher, reassign };
```

```
const functions = require("./watcher.js");
const watcher = functions.watcher;
watcher.addListener("change", (prev, variable) => {
    console.log(`Old value: ${prev}, New value: ${variable}`);
});
functions.reassign(10);
```